# An Error occurs when getting list data from another class in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, range

We just refer the 'group' reference and after that we created an initial function for create an object that this reference refers. Here is our code snippet:

```
Class className{Group group,List<Group> membersList; void initializeData(){group = new Group(args);membersList.add(group}}
```

We call it from ListTile. Here is the callback scope:

```
ListTile{leading:className.membersList[index].name}
```

We got RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid range value is empty : 0